# Number of subgroups of order $p$ in $C_{p} \times C_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for the number of subgroups of order $p$ in $C_{p} \times C_{p}$, using the double counting technique. I've tried doing it with Lagrange's theorem but don't make any progress. How should I do it? And how many normal subgroups are there of order $p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your group $G$ is abelian, so all subgroups are normal.

All elements (except the identity $e$) have order $p$. So $G$ contains $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

Thus a subgroup of order $p$ contains $e$, and $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

By Lagrange's Theorem, two distinct subgroup of order $p$ will have trivial intersection.

Therefore, if $k$ is the number of subgroups of order $p$, you will have $k (p-1) = p^2-1$.

Comment: I understand everything apart from the Lagrange's Theorem part. Why do two distinct subgroups of order $p$ have trivial intersection?

Comment: If the intersection has order greater than 1, then it has order $p$, and it is contained in both subgroups of the same order.

Comment: Is this because the intersection is a subgroup and is supposed to divide the order of the group, which is prime (or the power of a prime)?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: a group of the form $\;G=C_p\times C_p\times\ldots\times C_p\;$ is called *elementary abelian group*, and it always can be made into a linear vector space over **the field** $\;\Bbb F_p\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\cong C_p\;$ in the obvious way.

It's an easy exercise to check that $\;H\;$ subgroup of $\;G\iff H\;$ subspace of the space $\;G\;$, so your question can be reformulated as: how many one-dimensional subspaces as $\;G\;$?

In your case, we have $\;|G|=p^2\;$ and every vector different from zero spans a 1-dimensional subspace, which will have $\;p-1\;$ different non-zero elements (eac of which generates the very same subspace!), thus all in all there are

$$\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}=p+1\;\;\text{subspaces (subgroups) of order}\;\;p $$